# All probing URLs attempted and failed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, .net-assembly

I have a visual studio windoes application having N Number of projects. 
I am getting the below described error while running my setup.
this error is traced by Fusion log viewer:-

```
> The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\directory\InstallUtil.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = userdir\Alice.Carroll
LOG: DisplayName = Company.Shared.EnterpriseLibraryExtensions.resources, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=80955c93367666f4
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/directory/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\directory\InstallUtil.exe.Config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Company.Shared.EnterpriseLibraryExtensions.resources, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=80955c93367666f4
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/directory/en/Company.Shared.EnterpriseLibraryExtensions.resources.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/directory/en/Company.Shared.EnterpriseLibraryExtensions.resources/Company.Shared.EnterpriseLibraryExtensions.resources.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/directory/en/Company.Shared.EnterpriseLibraryExtensions.resources.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/directory/en/Company.Shared.EnterpriseLibraryExtensions.resources/Company.Shared.EnterpriseLibraryExtensions.resources.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

What may be the cause of this error?

Comment: Seems like you're missing some shared dll/exe files that your application depends on?